# Cannot resolve symbol MockedStatic

Tags: java, intellij-idea, import, mockito, pom.xml

I'm trying to import [MockedStatic](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.10.0/org/mockito/MockedStatic.html) into a test but am not having any luck. My pom.xml file contains:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I use the following line to build the project:

```
mvn clean -U install appengine:run -Dapp.devserver.port=8888 -DskipTests=true
```

I am using IntelliJ and I get a "cannot find symbol" error for the import:

```
import org.mockito.MockedStatic;
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What directory is the source file of the class doing the import in?

Comment: /src/test/java/.../

Comment: Do you get an error from the maven command, or just in Intellij IDEA? Perhaps you need to reload your project in the Maven tab?

Comment: Just Intellij IDEA. I don't see any maven tab... is this a plugin? I have maven helper installed.

Comment: Error from Maven command - means "mvn" binary in the command line.

Comment: Does it help to remove the scope?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out reloading project was all that was needed, as tgdavies suggested.

With Maven Helper plugin: right click on project folder > Run Maven > Reimport